# PostgreSQL Table Unresponsive/Corrupt when deleting

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, postgis, amazon-rds

Tables in my (Amazon RDS) PostgreSQL database seem to get corrupted and become unresponsive when I attempt to delete them. Is there a way to check if unresponsive tables are corrupted. Is it possible to forcefully delete them?

The storage on Amazon RDS is hitting its max, would this influence DB performance?

Comment: Absolutely, hitting max storage is a very bad idea with any database system.  They need to have extra space for 'juggling' the disk space it owns.  I'd recommend not using more than 80% of your disk space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Greg pointed out hitting the limit of the database server's storage seemed to be causing issues. On AWS I was able to resolve the issue by adjusting the available storage for the database (via Instance Actions -> Modify -> Allocated Storage).